# Highcharts Export to csv -Custom data

Tags: angular, highcharts, export-to-csv, custom-data-attribute

Highcharts : I am having a requirement to input custom data (string,image) in the exported csv chart of Highcharts in Angular 2?Some of the data in exported csv will be diffe

Comment: Provide us with the code that you created so far.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far?